# Ordenar valores de una tabla y copiarlos a otra en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

En una base de datos en mysql tengo las tablas `countries` y `countries2`, quiero ordenar alfabeticamente el contenido de la tabla countries por la columna `country_name` y una vez ordenado copiar esta consulta en la tabla countries2.
He intentado de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO countries2 SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country_name ASC;
```

Pero solo copia el contenido de la tabla `countries` a la tabla `countries2` sin ordenarla

Comment: Debería de funcionar tu código [AQUI TU CODIGO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqzif.png),[TABLA COUNTRIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvfIj.png),[TABLA COUNTRIES 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df3Qd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes un error de concepto, cuando insertas datos en una tabla mediante un select, no tiene ningun sentido ordenarlos, lo que tienes que hacer posteriormente es que hacer una consulta en la tabla en la que haces tu INSERT y ahi si ordenar la salida, porque realmente lo que haces es copiar exactamente los mismos datos de una tabla a otra.
Otro caso sería si tuvieses un autoincremental y entonces si que importa el orden, pero dada tu descripción tu código es correcto.